# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Japanese Language's [first moderator election<sup>*</sup>](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: snailboat] [image: Earthliŋ] [image: Flaw]

They'll be replacing [the pro tempore crew](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302/moderator-pro-tem-announcement) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes! And don't forget to share your appreciation with the Pro Tempore mods themselves, whose years of toil and guidance have brought us this far.

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4860784215588864/0).

<sup>*<sub>ignoring [The Troubles](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/restarting-the-election-nomination-phase-for-2015-moderator-election)</sub></sup>

Answer (score 8):

Woo hoo! :-)

I'm really excited to have three active moderators again.  Earthliŋ is an moderator on Sustainability and Portuguese, and I've always thought he'd make a good one here on Japanese.SE, too.  Flaw is a brand new moderator, but he seems to be picking things up rather quickly, and of course both Flaw and Earthliŋ are active contributors who care a lot about the site, so I'm really optimistic!  I think having this new moderator line-up is going to work out great.

I'd like to thank jkerian for his years of janitorship – that's his favorite way of describing being a moderator – and I hope he'll keep helping us maintain the site FAQs, just like he did before he ever became a moderator.  The FAQs are some of his best contributions to the site.

Let's keep trying our best to make this site the best resource it can be :-)